# Where to put Bluemix Service documentation

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

I have created a Bluemix Service and can see it in my Bluemix dashboard, under Services.

When I go into my service, under the Manage tab, there is a button, "Open my-service-name Dashboard".  When I click on it, I am taken to a page saying

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty Below is a rendering of
>   the page up to the first error.

It seems like I need to provide a documentation.  But where do I put that in my source code directory?

Comment: Did you provision a service out of the catalog or did you add your own service to Bluemix? If the latter, did you register a broker?

Comment: I am adding my own service to Bluemix, I registered a service broker, but I don't see any field that specifies this page in the json returned from /v2/catalog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service metadata has a field `documentationURL` that can be used to point to the related documentation. This and other fields like the `dashboard_client` (for the service dashboard) are documented in the [Cloud Foundry Catalog Metadata](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/catalog-metadata.html) in the section on [Services Metadata Fields](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/catalog-metadata.html#services-metadata-fields).

To see a working example you can take a look at my [Pseudo Broker/Service sample](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Bluemix-ServiceBroker) that I wrote for Bluemix. It has the bare minimum code and step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks henrik, the documentationURL seems to be the page that shows up when you click on the ... then click on 'View Docs'.
The page I am referring to is the page under the 'Manage' tab, where it says 'Open my-app-name Dashboard'.  Where can I specify which page that takes me to?

Comment: I added the dashboard info. It is in my example, too.